# How do I override entity framework code first convention for creating a foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a property on my items class called vend_id which of course EF thinks is a foreign key to the vendor table.  It actually should be a foreign key in the database but for reasons unknown to me the designers of the db chose not to make it a foreign key.
I am using EF to create a copy of the db schema on the local machine.  When EF creates the database I want to tell it not to create a foreign key on the vend_id column.  How do I do that?  Ideally I do not want to rename the property because there are several such instances in my db and it just makes it confusing.

Thank you,
Sam

Comment: Are you sure EF thinks `vend_id` is a FK to `Vendor`? Can you provide small piece of code which reproduces this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a navigation property to a `Vendor` entity in your `Item` entity class if the `Items` table does not have a foreign key to table `Vendor`.  If you did not specify a navigation property in entity class `Item`, EF would not infer that `vend_id` is a foreign key.

Update:

Unable to reproduce with the following:

```
[Table("EntityA")]
public partial class EntityA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EntityBId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey( "EntityBId" )]
    public virtual EntityB EntityB { get; set; }

    // this is not created as a FK
    //  nor does EntityCId cause a FK
    public int EntityC_Id { get; set; }
}

[Table("EntityC")]
public class EntityC
{
    public EntityC()
    {
        EntitiesD = new HashSet<EntityD>();
    }

    public int EntityCId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EntityD> EntitiesD { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you but there is no navigation property on my class and EF still infers the FK.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Post your entity classes

Comment: but there was a collections of items on the vend class!  I removed that and it works.  So the complete answer is to remove navigation properties off both ends.  Thanks Moho.